# Java iso 8601 universal date time format

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want this result on date time: `2008-10-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00`, please help me how i get this result?

I am using following code but unable to get required response.

```
TimeZone tzone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'"); 
String nowAsISO = dateformat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ

Comment: For starters, if you want 4 or 7 decimals on your seconds, you cannot use the `Date` class, it has only millisecond precision (3 decimals). You’re far from lost, though: it’s so much better of an opportunity to start using [the modern Java date and time API known as JSR-310 or `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Use the modern Java date and time API. The `toString` methods of its classes produce ISO-8601 format natively: `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5)).toString()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are quite right:

Your format expression is missing seconds `:ss`, millisecond `.SSS` (many `S` for how many digit you want) and the `Z` timezone tag without `'`

Using single quote `'` in the expression will exclude everything included in them from parsing, ergo you will have it printed like a string.

```
TimeZone tzone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"); 
String nowAsISO = dateformat.format(new Date());
```

You can see every possible pattern [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Wrong answer. We can specify only 3 pattern symbols "SSS" because the old `SimpleDateFormat`-API supports millisecond precision, not more. And the timezone should be set, too, but the code for that is also missing.

Comment: On my computer I got `2017-11-06T14:14:35.0000511+0100`. The decimals are wrong, they should at least be `.5110000`. And the OP asked for a colon in the offset (`-05:00`). Also you are not using your variable `tzone` for anything.

Comment: **Incorrect Answer**, as others commented about these classes supporting only milliseconds while the Question requires a resolution finer than microseconds. And this Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.